# GGplot2 not drawing trendline in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, trendline

All,

I have a fairly simple data frame organized with year and temperature in the first two columns:

A snippet:

```
>atemp_sum
   year     mean        anom
2  2007 20.39830  0.17591432
3  2008 19.89493 -0.32744991
4  2009 19.43331 -0.78907475
5  2010 19.07625 -1.14613367
6  2011 20.07615 -0.14623128
7  2012 20.00268 -0.21970282
```

I am trying to create a ggplot of the data with a trend line. I have tried this several different ways: running the lm separately and using geom_abline() and doing it directly in ggplot using geom_smooth. The results are the same. It draws the points, but no line and does not give me any error.

The code I'm running is here:

```
ggplot(atemp_sum, aes(x = year, y = mean)) + labs(x = "Year", y = "Temperature C") + geom_point()+ geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, col='red', size=2)
```

The results I am getting in the plot:

[plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZkqI.png)

I clearly am expecting a trend line in red to show the positive trend in temperatures.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: hi can you provide a dput of your data? the ggplot code seems fine

Comment: Try `ggplot(atemp_sum, aes(x = year, y = mean, group = 1)`. From your image I would guess that your year column is a character or factor. In that case you have to explicitly set the `group` aes so that all points are treated as one group.

Comment: Bingo! That was the problem. It's working great now.

Comment: be careful with trendlines: https://xkcd.com/2048/ ;-)